# How access elements Inside <script type="text/x-magento-template">

Tags: magento2, adminhtml

I am working at adminside. I have added my element inside script tag as shown below:

```
  <script class="dialog-template" type="text/x-magento-template" 
   data-title="Image Options">
          <! ..... Magento Default Code  ..... !>
        <div class="inline-labels" id="coords" class="container">
           <label>Test<input type="text" size="4" id="test" 
                                   name="test_[<%- data.file_id %>]" 
                                   value="" />
            </label>
        </div>
            <! ..... Magento Default Code  ..... !>
  </script>
```

I am not able to get access on test element. Its give undefine error while accessing it using jquery like

```
require([
          'jquery'
         ], function ($) {
          $(function () {
              alert($('#test').val());  
          });
      });
```

Answer (score 2):

The HTML inside script tag -`text/x-magento-template`- it's not a 'real' HTML, so, the Javascript selector will ignore it.
It can be extracted and generated HTML by Javascript.

We should take a look `vendor/magento/module-shipping/view/adminhtml/templates/order/tracking.phtml`. As we can see, after generating HTML, we can select the HTML selectors.

In your case, we should add like this:

```
<script>
    require([
    'mage/template',
    'prototype'
    ], function(mageTemplate){


        var dialogControl;

        dialogControl.template = mageTemplate('#dialog-template');

        dialogControl = {
            add : function () {
                Element.insert($('dialog-template-container'), {
                    bottom: this.template()
                });
                console.log($('test'));
            },

        };

    });
</script>
```

Comment: I updated my answer. We should have id `dialog-template` and `dialog-template-container` to your template.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are trying to get the value before the content of the template is rendered.

You can trigger a custom event with jQuery inside the `text/x-magento-template` block and then listen to that event in your JavaScript code.

Try this:

```
<script class="dialog-template" type="text/x-magento-template" 
   data-title="Image Options">
    <! ..... Magento Default Code  ..... !>
    <div class="inline-labels" id="coords" class="container">
        <label>Test<input type="text" size="4" id="test"                 
          name="test_[<%- data.file_id %>]" value="" />
        </label>
    </div>
    <! ..... Magento Default Code  ..... !>

    <% jQuery(document).trigger('tpl-block-rendered') %>
</script>
```

Then, in your require JS code you can listen to the event and retrieve the value:

```
require(['jquery'], function ($) {
    $(document).on('tpl-block-rendered', function() {
        alert($('#test').val());  
    });
});
```